# MicroKernelTrait.php on line 126 and at least 1 expected

Tags: symfony6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me estoy volviendo loco con este error, uso Symfony 6.2

```
php bin/console cache:clear
ArgumentCountError {#90
  #message: "Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer::__construct(), 0 passed in /Datos/web/fifpp/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php on line 126 and at least 1 expected"
  #code: 0
  #file: "./vendor/symfony/mailer/Mailer.php"
  #line: 32
  trace: {
    ./vendor/symfony/mailer/Mailer.php:32 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php:126 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:331 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:708 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:122 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:148 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:69 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:168 { …}
    ./vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/ConsoleApplicationRunner.php:54 { …}
    ./vendor/autoload_runtime.php:29 { …}
    ./bin/console:11 {
      › 
      › require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
      › 
      arguments: {
        "/Datos/web/fifpp/vendor/autoload_runtime.php"
      }
    }
  }
}
2023-04-02T12:40:57+00:00 [critical] Uncaught Error: Too few arguments to function Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer::__construct(), 0 passed in /Datos/web/fifpp/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Kernel/MicroKernelTrait.php on line 126 and at least 1 expected
```

En mi index en public uso esta función

```
public function registerBundles(): iterable
    {
        yield new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle();
    }
```

pero no consigo ver el problema. ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Comment: Si tienes la versión 6, [lee lo que dice la doc](https://symfony.com/doc/6.3/bundles.html): *En las versiones de Symfony anteriores a la 4.0, se recomendaba organizar tu propio código de aplicación mediante paquetes. Esto ya no se recomienda y los paquetes solo deben usarse para compartir código y funciones entre varias aplicaciones.* Si en tu caso se justifica el uso de Bundles, no uses `registerBundles()`, en los ejemplos del enlace te explican cómo deben agregarse los paquetes desde Symfony 5+. Tu código en ese punto es conforme la versión 4, pero ¡ya estás en la 6!, actualiza el código.

Comment: Lo que hice fue desinstalar Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer y ohh empezó a funcionar todo. Ahora lo que tenía pensado hacer como has dicho es mirar la doc para ver si he usar Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer u otra aplicación para el tratamiento de emails, porque su instalación hizo que petara todo, también tendré en cuenta lo que me comentas de registerBundles() gracias

Comment: Todo es más simple de lo que uno cree con Symfony, una vez has aprendido cómo funciona. Para el envío de correos revisa [este post](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html). Es bueno que leas siempre la documentación **actualizada** o entradas de blog recientes, porque en el caso de herramientas como Symfony las cosas van cambiando para mejor, simplificando procesos complejos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desinstalando

> Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer

arreglo a priori el problema.

Gracias igualmente